# Implement a method of abstract class when the current class already extends another class

Tags: java, class, abstract-class

I have a class which extends another class. Now when I want to implement a method of another class which is abstract I cannot instantiate as its abstract and cannot use 'extends' as my current class already extends something (cannot do multiple inheritance).

say my class is Class A which extends B and I want to use a method of abstract class C.

```
          Class A extends B{
          }

          abstract Class C { public List<String> method1(){//logic}; }
```

I tried declaring Class C as a variable and fetch the method. But that does not work. Can anybody suggest me a correct way please ? // Unfortunately cannot redesign the model

```
             private C cObject;
             cObject.method1(); // returns null
```

Comment: You must sub-class an `abstract` class to instantiate it, there is no implementation of `method1` in `C`.

Comment: Could you make C an interface? Then A could extend B and implement C.

Comment: use interfaces, re-design the model and implement as much as you need

Comment: Sorry just added it,  there is actually one. The abstract class has both abstract and concrete methods.@ElliottFrisch

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the model. I tried using the 'C' class like  'private C cobject' and cObject.method1(). I could access the method from Class A doing that, but Guess am doing something wrong or its not correct to do that.

Comment: Are you sure you can't make `method1` static?

Comment: As I understood it the method is not abstract. It's just inside an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

Do a mutli level inheritance. Extend Class C in Class B. So once you extend Class B in A you will be able to access method1()

OR

Create a new Class, extend Class C in the new Class. Now you will be able to instantiate the new class in Class A and access method1()

Comment: Thats a good idea, thanks -  but class B also extends something

Comment: Get that.. added more to the answer.